# Problema al actualizar un registro

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, wamp

Cuando quiero actualizar me salen 3 tablas que dicen

> notice:undefined variable: usuario in c....

Mi código es como se muestra abajo:

```
if(isset($_GET['cve_agregar'])){
  $cve_agregar = $_GET['cve_agregar'];
}
  if(isset($_GET['usuario'])){
    $usuario = $_GET['usuario'];
  }
  if(isset($_GET['contrasena'])){
    $contrasena = $_GET['contrasena'];
  }

try {
require_once('conexion.php');
$sql = "UPDATE agregar SET usuario = '$usuario', contrasena='$contrasena' WHERE cve_agregar=$cve_agregar";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
} catch(Exception $e){
    $error=$e->getMessage();
  }

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Actualizar</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">

    <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png">
      <h1 id="saludo">Mis de Contactos</h1> <br><br>
      <div class="contenido">

        <?php
          if($resultado === TRUE){
            echo "Contacto Actualizado";
          } else {
            echo "Error".$conexion->error;
          }
        ?>
        <br><br>
        <a class="volver" href="agregaruser.php" >Regresar a Principal</a>


      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
      $conexion->close();![este es el problema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnAhK.jpg)![este es el formulario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3MP6.jpg)![aquí inserto los datos del formulario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvZ64.jpg)
```

Comment: Cual es el problema?

Comment: deberias poner que es lo que pretendes y cual es el resultado que te arroja

Comment: Cuando quiero actualizar me salen 3 tablas que dicen notice:undefined variable: usuario in c....

Comment: Dódne está el formulario <form>? Lo podrías enseñar?

Comment: @Eduardo es muy importante formular adecuadamente las preguntas, para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar oportunamente. Respecto a tu problema (aunque no se alcanza a ver completo) puede ser porque la variable $_GET['usuario'] no esta llegando, asegurate que esta bien escrita en la URL. Al no existir la variable el If evalúa como falso y por eso no se crea la variable $usuario.

Comment: Para añadir información relevante a la pregunta (como, por ejemplo, la pregunta como tal, los logs de error o la descripción de lo que pasa y no debería pasar), por favor usa la opción para [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/182554/edit) la pregunta

Comment: te recomiendo revisar esto: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp